# The relationship between Wifi and Socket

Tags: c, sockets, wifi

What's the relationship between Wifi and Socket? Does Socket code below still applies where the Wifi connection is being made?

```
   // IPv4 AF_INET sockets:
struct sockaddr_in {
    short            sin_family;   // e.g. AF_INET, AF_INET6
    unsigned short   sin_port;     // e.g. htons(3490)
    struct in_addr   sin_addr;     // see struct in_addr, below
    char             sin_zero[8];  // zero this if you want to
};

struct in_addr {
    unsigned long s_addr;          // load with inet_pton()
};


    #include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h> //inet_addr

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    int socket_desc;
    struct sockaddr_in server;

    //Create socket
    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
    if (socket_desc == -1)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket");
    }

    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("74.125.235.20");
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons( 80 );

    //Connect to remote server
    if (connect(socket_desc , (struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        puts("connect error");
        return 1;
    }

    puts("Connected");
    return 
    struct sockaddr {
        unsigned short    sa_family;    // address family, AF_xxx
        char              sa_data[14];  // 14 bytes of protocol address
    };
```

Comment: What is the relation between the subway and the tunnel?

Answer (score 2):

You question is unclear. 
If I well understand you want to use socket to access to your wireless card.
In your example you don't use the proper type of socket. I'll give you an example to clarify.

First you need to open a socket type SOCK_RAW and use the return as a file descriptor. Then you will use this FD in goal to pass some command via ioctl() function.

```
int main() {

 struct ifreq ifr ; // for interface manipulation
 struct iwreq iwr ; // for wifi order (scan, connection...)

 int sock = socket(AF_PACKET,SOCK_RAW,0) // use htons(ETH_P_ALL) option to capture traffic
 if (sock == -1) {
  perror("socket error") ;

 /* Let's get the hardware address of your wifi interface */
 /* In my example the name of your wifi interface is wlan0 */

 memset(&ifreq,0,sizeof(struct ifreq)) 
 char hwaddr[6] ; 
 char ifname[5] ;
 strncpy(ifname,"wlan0",5) ; 
 memcpy(ifr.ifr_name,ifname,sizeof(ifr.ifr_name)) ; 
 ret = ioctl(sock,SIOCGIFHWADDR,&ifr) ; 
 if (ret < 0) 
  perror("error ioctl") ; 
 memcpy(hwaddr,ifr.ifr_name,6) ;
 printf("HWaddr : %s\n",hwaddr) ; 

 return 0 ;  

}
```

Note : This code doesn't include the headers file. A simple research on internet will give you its. 
I invite you to read all the commands you can made with ifreq structure : 
[Use ifreq](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl7_netdevice.htm)

For iwreq I prefer let you discover in here : 
[Use iwreq](http://blog.listincomprehension.com/2011/03/wireless-scanning-with-erlang.html)

If you want to make a tcpdump like with socket and wireless access (without using of pcap libraries) you can set an HTONS(ETH_P_ALL) option when you open your socket raw, and bind the index of your wireless interface to this socket (see SIOCGIFINDEX ioctl and sockaddr_ll struct). A simple recv() from this socket will give you all the traffic top to the physical layer. After that you will need to learn how to interpret the data receives.

Hope it'll help you.

Anthony

Comment: I think the OP just want to know if the same code could work with ethernet or wifi ... But yeah the question is unclear :/

Comment: Okay, if it's the case, the question is really unclear, as the source code... It's depends of what he wants to do, if it's simply send data by wifi yes it's the same (so nouney tells right). But if he wants go deeper in the OSI models, is really differents (radiotap package) Thanks mate !

Answer (score 1):

> What's the relationship between Wifi and Socket? Does Socket code below still applies where the Wifi connection is being made?

Yes. The socket API is an abstraction layer and doesn't depend on the network interface. There's not relationship between Wifi and socket, *in your code*.